# Is it possible to turn an array to a Result<> in Realm?

Tags: arrays, swift, realm

I use the following query in my app to filter Folders where the categories (array) id equals the one the user selected (`categoryId`)

```
func getFoldersForCategory(_ categoryId:Int, sorting:String) -> Results<Folder> {
   let realm = try! Realm()
   let realmObjects = realm.objects(Folder.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "producerName", ascending: true).filter("toDate >= %@ AND language == %@", getCurrentLocalDateWithoutTimeStamp(), ApplicationSettingsRealm().getCurrentLanguage())

   return realmObjects.filter({ $0.categories.filter({ $0.id == categoryId }) != [] })
 }
```

The above code used to work when I returned an array of `[Folder]` (hence `getFoldersForCategory(_ categoryId:Int, sorting:String) -> [Folder]`.
I recently wanted to change the return to the results from the Realm query.

Now my code isn't working anymore, because I can't filter this way with `Results<Folder>`. The error I receive is

> Unable to infer closure type in the current context

So I was wondering if there is a way that I can convert the last line of code from an array to a Realm Results<>

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot. However, assuming that `categories` is a Realm `List`, you can simply include that filter in the query rather than converting it to an array:

```
func getFoldersForCategory(_ categoryId:Int, sorting:String) -> Results<Folder> {
   let realm = try! Realm()
   return realm.objects(Folder.self)
               .sorted(byKeyPath: "producerName", ascending: true)
               .filter("toDate >= %@ AND language == %@ AND ANY categories.id == %@",
                       getCurrentLocalDateWithoutTimeStamp(),
                       ApplicationSettingsRealm().getCurrentLanguage(),
                       categoryID)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I didn't see this sooner! Sometimes a different look helps